# Common Table Expression [CTE] and INNER JOIN

Tags: postgresql, inner-join, common-table-expression

My question is very simple. Here is my code:

```
 WITH P1 as  
(
SELECT (count(*)) as Premier_trimestre
FROM import.dvf1,
    (SELECT commune FROM import.dvf1) as commune
WHERE   date_mutation BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2020-03-31' 
 GROUP BY dvf1.commune
)
, P2 as  
(
SELECT (count(*)) as Deuxieme_trimestre
FROM import.dvf1, (select commune FROM import.dvf1) as commune
WHERE   date_mutation BETWEEN '2020-04-01' AND '2020-06-30' 
 GROUP BY dvf1.commune
)


    SELECT * 
FROM
     P1 t1
     INNER JOIN 
     P2 t2
     ON t1.commune = t2.commune
```

When I run it, I get:

```
ERROR:  column t1.commune does not exist
LINE 23:      ON t1.commune = t2.commune
                ^
SQL state: 42703
Character: 471
```

I don't understand why.I tried to rename commune, to move it, etc., but I cannot find a fix.

Comment: Also, the query takes forever, i am sure there is a more clever way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CTEs only yield one column named `Premier_trimestre` or `Deuxieme_trimestre`.

If you want to include the commune column from import.dvf1 then you need to include it in the SELECT list of the CTEs.

You are also creating a cross join of the table with itself with this part `FROM import.dvf1, (SELECT commune FROM import.dvf1)` which is most probably the reason why the query takes forever.

I *think* what you intended is:

```
WITH P1 as  
(
  SELECT dvf1.commune, -- this "exposes" the commune column
         count(*) as Premier_trimestre
  FROM import.dvf1
  WHERE dvf1.date_mutation BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2020-03-31' 
  GROUP BY dvf1.commune
)
, P2 as 
(
  SELECT dvf1.commune,  
         count(*) as Deuxieme_trimestre
  FROM import.dvf1
  WHERE dvf1.date_mutation BETWEEN '2020-04-01' AND '2020-06-30' 
  GROUP BY dvf1.commune
)
SELECT * 
FROM P1     
  JOIN P2 ON p1.commune = p2.commune
```

However, you can simplify this substantially by using filtered
aggregation:

```
SELECT commune, 
       count(*) filter (where extract(month from dvf1.date_mutation) in (1,2,3)) as Premier_trimestre, 
       count(*) filter (where extract(month from dvf1.date_mutation) in (4,5,6)) as Deuxieme_trimestre
FROM import.dvf1 
WHERE dvf1.date_mutation BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2020-06-30'  -- this covers both ranges
GROUP dvf1.commune
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I am going forward. My probleme was indeed "exposing" the commune column.

Comment: Thank you for opening for me  the gate to the world of filtered aggregation :)))
I just can't get enought now!